# WordPress/PHP - how to move variable to non-wordpress file?

Tags: php, wordpress

When I execute this code in `functions.php` I get the path:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
echo $upload_dir['path'];

//Returns: /some/correct/path/
```

But I want this path to be moved to my custom script located in `uploads.php` where I can't execute `wp_upload_dir();`. I obviously can't `include()` functions.php either because it would execute everything else that is located there.

Is there any tricky way to pass `$upload_dir` variable to `uploads.php`?

Comment: If my solution worked, please select it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to load **wp-load.php** it will give you access to all wordpress functions, just do something like this:

```
<?php
   require( '../wordpress_install_root/wp-load.php' );
   $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
   echo $upload_dir['path'];
?>
```

This is an easy way.

Comment: Great! Hmm, but how do I know what the correct WP path is? I'm developing theme for more people that can have various setups. Like theme folder nested within 5 other folders etc.

Comment: That's a problem outside wordpress, i suggest to put the same file at the wordpress root and use: <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?> to get the same path, if it is a theme, you can use a relative path with: <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../../wp-load.php'; ?> (please check the correct number of ../ ?>

Comment: There are two possible locations for `wp-load.php`: one in the wp directory, a second one directory above.

Comment: No, there should be only one at wordpress root folder.

Answer (score 1):

just include the following at the top of your external php file:

```
$wp_url = str_replace('wp-content/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME/includes', "", dirname(__FILE__));
include_once($wp_url . 'wp-load.php');
```

obviously replace YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME with the name of your plugin. I use it in a single file that is being called by Paypal and other payment gateways.

Some also use the following but i never got it to work properly and I'm unsure if it is deprecated.

```
require_once('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just wondering one last thing - how do I determine correct path? I'm developing theme for more people and some of them may put that file in like: wp-content/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME/CUSTOM_FOLDER/CUSTOM_FOLDER2/includes and I can't really know how is it going to look like in their case.